# Load Firestore datas into a json

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to load my Firestore Datas into a json which is in my actual App included ?

DocumentReference ingredientsRef = db.document("res/ingredientsList");

```
    ingredientsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete{@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful() {
                DocumentSnapshot ingredientdocument = task.getResult();
```

}

in this if clause should be the opportunity to load the data of my firestore into my json somehow... thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore doesn't store JSON, it stores only pairs of key and value with strongly typed values. When you read a document from your database in Android, you have two choices to get a hold of those fields. One would be to automatically map the the pairs of key and value to a POJO that conforms to `JavaBeans` standards. Please note that the `JSONObject` is not a valid JavaBean type object or the second approach would be to access each key and value pair out of the document individually.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firestore REST API, see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

You would call it with an URL that is like:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
```

You will receive the data directly in JSON format.

You can query a specific Document or an entire Collection.

---

Note, however, that it is a bit an unconventional approach to query the database, but it is one possibility. The documentation says the following:

> "While  the easiest way to use Cloud Firestore is to use one of the
>   native client libraries, there are some situations when it is useful
>   to call the REST API directly".